# Python CLIPS|Pattern for italian language

Tags: python, nlp, preprocessor

i need help to use this library with Italian Language.

I'm trying to use Pattern to create a dataset (to perform NMF) of Italian Feed RSS/ATOM but i don't know how to do it because the Lemmatizer won't work with italian sentence.

I'm using as guideline this [examples](https://github.com/clips/pattern/blob/master/examples/05-vector/01-document.py) with an italian text from wikipedia. but the result is the same of the input string.

Any suggestion?

edit: my code is this

```
from pattern.vector import Document, PORTER, LEMMA

s="Il ciclo, scritto all'inizio degli anni novanta, si svolge in un universo dove, al termine di una guerra tra le due potenti razze dei Sartan e dei Patryn, la Terra è stata suddivisa in quattro mondi ognuno dominato da un elemento (aria, acqua, terra e fuoco), mentre in un quinto, detto il Labirinto (una prigione senziente estremamente letale), i Sartan, vincitori del conflitto, hanno relegato i Patryn e sono misteriosamente scomparsi subito dopo. Secoli dopo i primi Patryn riescono a fuggire dal labirinto ed a penetrare negli altri mondi. I sette libri narrano le vicende di Haplo, un agente dei Patryn inviato ad esplorare i quattro mondi per preparare l'arrivo del suo padrone."

document = Document(s, threshold=1, stopwords=False)
documentP = Document(s, threshold=1, stopwords=False, stemmer=PORTER)
documentL = Document(s, threshold=1, stopwords=False, stemmer=LEMMA)

print document.words
{u'le': 2, u'dei': 3, u'patryn': 4, u'labirinto': 2, u'dopo': 2, u'sartan': 2, u'di': 2, u'quattro': 2, u'terra': 2, u'mondi': 3, u'e': 3, u'una': 2, u'un': 4, u'del': 2, u'il': 2}
print documentL.words
{u'le': 2, u'dei': 3, u'patryn': 4, u'mondi': 3, u'labirinto': 2, u'dopo': 2, u'sartan': 2, u'di': 2, u'quattro': 2, u'terra': 2, u'e': 3, u'una': 2, u'un': 4, u'del': 2, u'il': 2}
print documentP.words
{u'il': 2, u'le': 2, u'dei': 3, u'patryn': 4, u'labirinto': 2, u'dopo': 2, u'sartan': 2, u'di': 2, u'quattro': 2, u'terra': 2, u'mondi': 3, u'e': 3, u'una': 2, u'un': 4, u'del': 2}
```

Comment: Added code to main post.